# Reduce config tables:SymmetricDS

Tags: database, symmetricds

Well i'm trying to migrate data from my in-memory DB1 to my DB2. For this I'm using SymmetricDS configured in such a way that, when SymmetricDS starts, it will perform an inital load from DB1 to DB2. Furthermore whenever some data modification occurs in DB1, the same is pulled to DB2.

Now this is where i have a problem. SymmetricDS requires configuration tables or Sym Tables to be present at both the DB1 side and DB2 side.

Since my DB1 is in-memory, these configuration tables are taking a lot of memory.

So what I would like to know is **whether there is a way ,to keep the configuration tables entirely in a seperate on-disk db, from DB1 side, and yet retain the existing functionality?**

Hope i was able to make myself clear.

Any and all suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** Minimize runtime tables footprint.  You can aggressively purge the runtime tables.  For example, purge them every 10 minutes and only keep 10 minutes worth of activity:

```
purge.retention.minutes=10
job.purge.incoming.cron=0 */10 * * * *
job.purge.outgoing.cron=0 */10 * * * *
```

Avoid recording the incoming_batch table altogether:

```
incoming.batches.record.ok.enabled=false
```

**Option 2:** Put SymmetricDS in another database.  Setup SymmetricDS to point to a database, like H2 file-based database.  That's where all the "SYM" tables will go.  Then configure "jdbc" parameters to load into your in-memory database. For example, you could load into Apache Ignite:

```
jdbc.db.url=jdbc:ignite:thin://localhost
jdbc.db.driver=org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver
jdbc.db.user=
jdbc.db.password=
```

Then set the sym_channel.data_loader_type to "jdbc" for the channels you're using to load data (such as "default" and "reload" channels).

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the response. But could you elaborate a bit more on **Option 2**? Are you saying that all the sym tables can be loaded into file-based hsql db(`jdbc:hsqldb:file:db`) and the replicated data can be stored in memory-based hsqldb(`jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db`)?

Comment: If this is possible, what would be the `jdbc.db.url` that i would have to specify in the .properties file? The url of my file-based db or my memory-based db?

Comment: Also if i'm giving url of my file-based db as `jdbc.db.url` in .properties file and giving `sym_channel.data_loader_type` as `jdbc` then where should i mention the jdbc url of my memory-based db so that the replicated data will be loaded into my memory-based db?

Comment: I'm terribly new to symmetricds, so please forgive my ignorance and shed some light on my doubts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SymmetricDS 3.9 will provide a "load only" feature that will allow you to load into a database and have the sym tables created in an on disk H2 database.   This would allow you to replicate to your D2 without any sym tables in it.

Comment: can you tell me when 3.9 might be released?

Answer (score 0):

Low hanging fruit would be to decrease the purge period, i.e. decrease the parameter `job.purge.period.time.ms` from five days (in seconds -- 7200000) to few hours. SymmetricDs would clean all successfully synchronized outgoing batches (`sym_outgoin_batch`) and associated extracted data (`sym_data`) more often keeping the memory footprint lower.

SymmetricDs allows keeping its tables in another catalog and/or schema which doesn't really solve your problem.